# Number of objects with distinct property in a list

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a simple data set

```
data = [
    {'artist':'a','song':'a'},
    {'artist':'a','song':'b'},
    {'artist':'a','song':'c'},
    {'artist':'b','song':'d'},
    {'artist':'b','song':'e'},
    {'artist':'c','song':'f'},
    {'artist':'d','song':'g'},
    {'artist':'d','song':'h'},
    {'artist':'d','song':'i'}
];
```

Is there any native function in javascript or jQuery that would allow me to get the number of disctinct artist in a concise expression ?

Comment: The number of distinct artists? Or simply the length of this array?

Comment: Dictinct artists, I edited my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the number of distinct artists you can use this:

```
Object.keys(data.reduce(function(p, c) { p[c.artist] = 1 ; return p }, {})).length
```

this being a one liner that accumulates the distinct values of `c.artist` in the object `p`, then counts how many keys there are.

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this:

```
var array = [{"artist":"a","song":"a"}, {"artist":"a","song":"b"}, {"artist":"a","song":"c"}]
var unique = {};
var distinct = [];
    for( var i in array ){
     if( typeof(unique[array[i].song]) == "undefined"){
      distinct.push(array[i].song);
     }
     unique[array[i].song] = 0;
    }
var d = document.getElementById("d");
d.innerHTML = "" + distinct;
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jbUKP/121/)

Answer (score 0):

try this, **[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ashish_88/51txhdvg/1/)** here

```
data = [
    {'artist':'a','song':'a'},
    {'artist':'a','song':'b'},
    {'artist':'a','song':'c'},
    {'artist':'b','song':'d'},
    {'artist':'b','song':'e'},
    {'artist':'c','song':'f'},
    {'artist':'d','song':'g'},
    {'artist':'d','song':'h'},
    {'artist':'d','song':'i'}
];
newdata=[];
$.each(data, function(index,value){
newdata[index]=data[index].artist;
});

alert($.unique(newdata));
```

Comment: The only supported use for `$.unique` is on an Array of DOM Elements. It shouldn't be used on any other data even if it seems to work since its behavior when used in an unsupported way could change in the future.

Comment: The only supported use for `$.unique` is on an Array of DOM Elements. You have an Array of strings.

Comment: Hmm thanks @cookiemonster, your are right, but It is supporting for string also